# Changing second line text using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, text

I work with several maps with this text:

[image]

[image]

and i try to change the second line only into "landUse" by using this code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for num, mxdname in enumerate((arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")),start = 1):
    print '\n',num,mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(
    r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        elm.text = elm.text.replace(u'aaa'[1], u'landUse')
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

when i run it i get this unwanted result:

[image]

whereas i want this result:

[image]

i didn't find an answer in [Changing part of text element using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180199/changing-part-of-text-element-using-arcpy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing both the newline and 'aaa':

```
.replace('\naaa', "\nTEXT_ELEMENT")
```