# Changing fifth line of text using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, text

Subsequent to [Changing second line text using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322516), I want to know how can I change the fifth line from 'aaa' into 'plan b'

[image]

so the result will be:

[image]

with this code, by using index operator [5] and not with the solution of using the characters: '\n\n\n\n\n':

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for num, mxdname in enumerate((arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")),start = 1):
    print '\n',num,mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(
    r"G:\desktop\Project\\" + mxdname)
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        elm.text = elm.text.replace(u'aaa', u'landUse')[5]
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

but when i run it, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\desktop\y\test - עותק.py", line 10, in <module>
    elm.text = elm.text.replace(u'aaa', u'landUse')[5]
IndexError: string index out of range
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A google on "python replace nth occurence of string" will take you here: [Replace nth occurrence of substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091557/replace-nth-occurrence-of-substring-in-string) and the accepted answer has a function for it:

```
def nth_repl(s, sub, repl, nth):
    find = s.find(sub)
    # if find is not p1 we have found at least one match for the substring
    i = find != -1
    # loop util we find the nth or we find no match
    while find != -1 and i != nth:
        # find + 1 means we start at the last match start index + 1
        find = s.find(sub, find + 1)
        i += 1
    # if i  is equal to nth we found nth matches so replace
    if i == nth:
        return s[:find]+repl+s[find + len(sub):]
    return s


a = "hello\nhello\nhello\nhello\nhello"
print(nth_repl(a, '\nhello', '\ngoodbye',3))
```

Or split into list, replace one element, join back to string:

```
a = "hello\nhello\nhello\nhello\nhello"
b = a.split('\n')
b[3] = 'goodbye'
a = "\n".join(b)
```

Comment: where i engage this function in my code?

Comment: I dont have ArcGIS on this computer so I cant try it but i think: `elm.text = nth_repl(elm.text, '\nhello', '\ngoodbye',3)` and the function definition after `from arcpy import env`